# Primefaces datatable filterBy String

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, filter, datatable

I have already read suggested posts, but none of them worked for my issue. The problem is that when selecting a criteria to filter by, nothing happens.

[image]

```
<h:form id="form"> 

        <p:dataTable var="task" value="#{searchMB.tasksBean}" 
                    emptyMessage="No tasks found with given criteria"
                     widgetVar="tasksTable"  filteredValue="#{searchMB.filteredTasks}">

            <p:column headerText="Priority" filterBy="#{task.priority}" filterMatchMode="in">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <p:selectCheckboxMenu label="Show only.." onchange="PF('tasksTable').filter()" panelStyle="width:125px" scrollHeight="50">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{searchMB.priorities}" />
                    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
                 </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{task.priority}" />
            </p:column>
```

In the backing bean there is nothing special, just the method that is loading tasks and lists for tasks, filteredTasks and priorities for selectmenu.

Please advise.

Update (links I tried)

[primefaces Datatable filter is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166118/primefaces-datatable-filter-is-not-working) - i don't know why this is not working, nothing happens. I also tried with contains, to search for a signle priority at once.

[FilterBy using column doesn't work in primefaces 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529787/filterby-using-column-doesnt-work-in-primefaces-5-3)  - nothing happens

[Primefaces dataTable filter search By not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970922/primefaces-datatable-filter-search-by-not-found) - nothing happens, too

Comment: _"I have already read suggested posts, "_ which ones? See [ask]

Comment: @Kukeltje , firstly thank you very much for your interest. Here are some links that I thought might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765075/primefaces-datatable-filtering-not-working  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32166118/primefaces-datatable-filter-is-not-working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970922/primefaces-datatable-filter-search-by-not-found  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529787/filterby-using-column-doesnt-work-in-primefaces-5-3

Comment: Please add that to your question... better readable. And also explain why they did not help

Comment: See the color column at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml

Comment: @JasperdeVries I don't notice any difference between their example and my code.

Comment: I could not tell based on the information you've put here. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, searched long, from browser console log saw this error- "uncaught type error: cannot read property 'keycode' of undefined"

This was due to jQuery conflict, I have disabled all jQuery imports and working fine. Got the solution here-

[<p:autoComplete> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'keyCode' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552160/pautocomplete-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-keycode-of-undefined)